# OS X memset and system trace

Tags: c, macos, instruments, memset

Here is a simplified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void *worker(void *data) {
    size_t size = 1000000;
    void *area = malloc(size);
    if (area != NULL) {
        memset(area, 0, size);
        sleep(1);
        free(area);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int number_of_threads = 4;
    pthread_t threads[number_of_threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, worker, NULL)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following system trace with the command `iprofiler -systemtrace OSXMalloc`:

[image]

Why does `memset` produce all this Zero Fill events? What do they mean and why so many? I understand that I try to fill 1 MB with zero but why it doesn't do this in one single call for each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security and privacy purposes, the kernel needs to guarantee that pages that are newly allocated to a process are filled with zeroes. Otherwise, you could get data from some other process, including, for example, passwords or financial information.

The pages are zeroed on first access, sort of similar to copy-on-write. Since `memset()` will iterate through the pages zeroing them out, the kernel will zero-fill the pages one at a time. `memset()` then does a bunch of redundant work writing zeroes on already-zeroed pages.

You would be better served by using `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` followed by `memset(..., 0, ...)`. Since the malloc library knows that the kernel will zero-fill freshly-allocated pages, it knows it doesn't need to do an explicit `memset()` to satisfy the zero-filling contract of `calloc()`. There will still be the zero-fill faults at first access, but they will happen when the memory is *really* being used for the first time. They won't be done "eagerly" for an unneeded `memset()`.

By the way, not all allocations done through `malloc()` get new pages from the kernel. Some will reuse pages previously allocated and freed within your process. However, for large allocations like you're doing, the pages are typically allocated during `malloc()` and deallocated during `free()`.

Comment: I was wondering if the guaranteed-ness of a Zero Fill could lead to readers assuming "oh then I don't really have to clear memory, *ever* again!" So, good point in mentioning in-process memory reallocation! (For which, dear readers, it would *not* Zero Fill.) I came here to upvote and chew bubblegum, but for today I'm all out of upvotes. Will call back soon. (Wait! I had one more!)

Answer (score 2):

It is not the `memset` that you see reported here, but rather the act of mapping the page into memory for later use. The OS fills the pages with zeroes to prevent data leaking from one application to another.

Each of the Zero Fill events you see is generated once for each memory *page*. A single memory page is only 4K long -- 4096 bytes --, so your contiguous chunk of 1 million bytes spans 245, and possibly 246, single pages.

This Zero Fill event may not be necessary for all memory pages. Some of them may have been zeroed during idle CPU time (and the OS keeps a list of "ready to go" memory pages), while other pages may be allocated but never get used. However, in this case the `memset` itself attempts to access every single byte, and so the OS has no other choice but to clear the page just before memset reaches it.

Comment: You answer was helpful too because it has some details and also you helped with editing question. Thank you and sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

there are going to be 4 threads, each of which will be calling malloc and memset, so the 4 instances are fully accounted for.

However, there is a bug in the code.

1. pre-set the `pthread_t` array to all zeros.
2. if any call to `pthread_create` fails, re-set the associated `pthread_t` entry to `0`
3. do not exit the program if a call to pthread_create fails
4. during the loop that calls `pthread_join`, 
   if the associated `pthread_t` entry is `0`
   then, do not call `pthread_join` for that entry.

otherwise, program is exiting when there may be active pthreads.

Comment: First of all this is a demo program just for demonstrating system trace output and your advices about code are out of scope. Second thing is that my question is about Zero Fill events amount. I understand that my code allocate memory and fill it with zeroes, thank you.